# Cuando concateno un String no aparece en consola

Tags: java

En un ejercicio de un curso me pide que invierta una cadena de caracteres pero al  concatenarla con system.out.println no  me imprime nada Pd: Eclipse no me marca ningun error.

```
public class InvertirStrings {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Scanner entrada = new Scanner (System.in);

        String CadenaInvertida = "";

        char car;

        System.out.println("Introduce tu frase");

        String frase = entrada.next();

        for (int i = frase.length(); i < 0; i--) {


              car  =  frase.charAt(i) ;

              CadenaInvertida += car;

        }

        System.out.println("Tu frase invertida es: " + CadenaInvertida);

    }

}
```

Comment: Revisa la condición de tu for, ya que jamas ingresa a ella.

Answer (score 0):

Cambia el signo de menor que cero a mayor que 0
    public class Main
    {

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
String CadenaInvertida = "";

char car;

System.out.println("Introduce tu frase");

String frase = "HOLA";

for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--) {


      car  =  frase.charAt(i) ;
     System.out.println(car);
      CadenaInvertida += car;

}

System.out.println("Tu frase invertida es: " + CadenaInvertida);
```

}
}
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No entiendo  no me va.

Comment: Es cuestión de que entiendas de que va el ciclo for, en tu código inicias i en la longitud de tu cadena, y le dices que se repita el ciclo mientras i sea menor a 0(inicialmente no pasa) , por esta razón no estas entrando en el ciclo y tu código hace nada

Comment: Gracias ahora ya entiendo